# Solve and NSolve for large models

Tags: algorithm, wolfram-mathematica

I'm a Mathematica rookie running version 7 on a 2010 MacBook Pro.

I'm trying to solve an economics problem with a large number of firms, where each firm is given a maximum production quota (i.e., rights to produce). The firms are of different sizes, larger ones being more efficient than smaller ones. There is a market for quotas, thus small, inefficient firms can shut down and sell their quota rights to larger ones; the quota price k must be computed endogenously.

The issue is as follows: with a small number of firms n (from 2 to 3), only Solve works, while NSolve gives me {}, i.e., no solution.
With a medium number of firms (from 4 to 7), only NSolve works.
With 8 and 9 firms, NSolve produces {}.
With 10 to 16 firms, NSolves works fine.
With a larger number of firms (17 and above), the evaluation keeps running without end and I end up aborting (I waited up to 15 minutes).

My hope was to run the model with thousands of firms. My questions are (1) how can I systematically get Mathematica to converge to the solution for an arbitrary large system and (2) why does NSolve not work for small systems.

Two remarks:

(1) You will notice some clunkiness in the way I set up the model, starting with a guess k0 for k, which determines which firms are operating and which ones are shutting down. Then for the list of operating firms, I compute the profit maximizing amount of labor, total output, and equilibrium k. If k is different from k0, I restart the computation with k0=k. The question of how to create a more elegant one-step program is a separate issue, though, and I don't think it is connected to what appears to be a model size limitation.

(2) If I solve the model for, say, 11 firms and then jump trying to solve for, say, 13 firms, Mathematica ends up running "endlessly". But if I solve for 12 firms first, then solving for 13 firms is a matter of seconds. So it would seem that despite the ClearAll["Global`*"] statement at the beginning of the notebook, it is as if Mathematica seemed to start with a better starting point.

I'm ready to be humbled :)

Here is the code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
(* Aggregate Quota Allocation *)
alloc=1000000;
(* Number of firms; *)
nv=4;
(* Equal quota allocation to each firm; *)
qbar = alloc/nv;
(* Firm sizes vary in amount of capital from smallest to largest;*)
vsmin=0 ;
vsmax=900000 ;
(* Assume discrete uniform distribution of firm sizes;*)
dvs=(vsmax-vsmin)/(nv-1) ;
(* List all firms by size; *)
listvs=Table[vs,{vs,vsmin,vsmax,dvs}]  ;
(* A firm's capital cost per annum is 10 percent of capital size;*)
g=0.1 ;
(* Avoidable fixed cost of operation;*)
f=5000 ;
(* Parameters of production function (same for all firms);*)
a=0.01 ;
alpha=0.7 ;
(* Price of output; *)
p=5;
(* Price of labor (daily wage);*)
wa=100 ;
(* Firm vs is a profit maximizer setting optimal number of days of operation tl[vs] ;
Firms that are too small are better off leasing their quota allocation to larger ones; 
The quota leasing price k is computed endogenously;
Firms will exit if "netprofitstay" is less than 0;
We are looking for threshold firm, whose size nvs1 is just above threshold size vs0;
All firms who size is nvs1 or larger are operating, the others are shutting down;
For now, we are setting the problem up as a manual loop, setting k0 = "k opt" 
from previous computation ; *)

k0=4.891714989052472` ;

profitstay0[tl0_,vs0_]:= (p-k0)(a vs0 tl0^alpha) - wa tl0 + k0 qbar - g vs0 - f  ;
netprofitstay0[tl0_,vs0_]:=(p-k0)(a vs0 tl0^alpha) - wa tl0 - f  ;
sol0:=NSolve[{D[profitstay0[tl0,vs0],tl0]==0 ,netprofitstay0[tl0,vs0]==0} ,{tl0,vs0}]  ;
vs1:=vs0/.Last[sol0] 
nvs0:=Part[Nearest[listvs,vs1],1] ;
nvs1:=If[nvs0<vs1,nvs0+dvs,nvs0] ;
(* List of firms who operate when k=k0; *)
listvsop:=Table[vs,{vs,nvs1,vsmax,dvs}]  ;

(* Production function;*)
eq[tl[vs_],vs_]:=a vs tl[vs]^alpha ;
(* Profit; *)
profitstay[k_,tl[vs_],vs_]:=(p-k) eq[tl[vs],vs] - wa tl[vs] + k qbar - g vs - f  ;
(* List of first-order conditions for a maximum; *)
foc:=Table[D[profitstay[k,tl[vs],vs],tl[vs]]==0,{vs,listvsop}]  ;
(* List of all endogenous variables; *)
variables:=Flatten[{k,Table[tl[vs],{vs,listvsop}]},1] ;
Print[variables] ;
(* List of all equations, including the one specifying that aggregate quota demand = aggregate
quota supply; *)
equations:=Flatten[{foc,Sum[eq[tl[vs],vs],{vs,listvsop}]==alloc }] ;
Print[equations] ;

(* Find solution;*)
NSolve[equations,variables]
```

Comment: If I just try to run your code as is I get a long stream of errors that appear to be the result of getting an empty list of solutions and then trying to take the last of those, create tables from the last of those, etc. Are you seeing all those errors? Can you explain what to do about those?

Comment: Dear Bill, I copied/pasted the code as posted on this forum into a new notebook and ran it without any trouble; got the solution without any errors. Specifically, I got: {{k -> 4.89171, tl[600000] -> 155.857, tl[900000] -> 602.138}}  Thanks!

Comment: Start MMA, empty notebook, copy, paste, add $Version, evaluate, get In[1]:= $Version Out[1]= "9.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 25, 2013)" In[2]:= ClearAll... Last::nolast: {} has a length of zero and no last element. >> ReplaceAll::reps: {Last[{}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >> again and again, etc. Don't know. Since you have it working perhaps you can find his solution. Thanks

Comment: @Bill : I'm not sure what would cause the errors in your case. The only major difference I can think of is the software version. I'm running 7.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (February 19, 2009) on this home/vacation laptop, not version 8 as previously claimed. Further output is {k,tl[600000],tl[900000]} in response to the first Print[] command, {-100+(4200. (5-k))/tl[600000]^0.3==0,-100+(6300. (5-k))/tl[900000]^0.3==0,6000. tl[600000]^0.7+9000. tl[900000]^0.7==1000000} in response to second Print[] command, then the solution as previously stated. Best,

Comment: Same question now posted on the Mathematica stackexchange forum, so we may want to close it here. Thanks.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55894/solve-and-nsolve-for-large-models